# How important is to use a <div> to render ExtJS layouts

Tags: html, extjs

I'm begining with ExtJS, and don't really understand how important it is. I mean, in my first try-out application, I'm no using any  because all the data is displayed in the containers created with ExtJS.

Can anyone give me a simple example when it is necessary to use the  tag to render ExtJS components?

Thanks a lot
Carlos

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can render Ext. to divs if your project is not APP, let say you have a "normal" html page, and just need a grid. In that case you can use renderTo(), but creating all content dinamically is prefered way for ExtJs. This way your body is clean, and Ext creates data based on user reactions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have your project setup, if everything will be contained in lets say a single viewport. Then I guess you don't need to worry about div's to hold different containers, however it will keep your layout much cleaner otherwise to do so